# PackageKit version issue after upgrading from fc21 -> fc22 -> fc23

Tags: fedora, gnome

I'm trying to build a package using `jhbuild`, and when I run `sysdeps --install`, it runs through and tries to install things using PackageKit.

When it does this, it shows for example, `llvm-devel;3.5.0-6.fc21;x86_64;updates`, but I'm no longer on fc21 and it eventually times out trying to download. If I just manually install all of the dependencies, it progresses, but I'd rather fix the root cause.

I've tried the obvious things like rebuilding the rpmdb, clearing the various caches, removing the PackageKit database files and running pkcon repair, none of which helped.

Also, if I list the repositories using dnf or pkcon they all show as fc23. Not sure where to look next.

Sample output:

```
$ cat /etc/fedora-release
Fedora release 23 (Twenty Three)

$ jhbuild sysdeps --install gnome-weather
System installed packages which are new enough:
  <long and unnecessary output removed>
Required packages:
  System installed packages which are too old:
    (none)
  No matching system package installed:
    libarchive (libarchive.pc, required=3.0.0)
Optional packages: (JHBuild will build the missing packages)
  System installed packages which are too old:
    (none)
  No matching system package installed:
I: Installing dependencies on system: libarchive
I: Installing:
  libarchive-devel;3.1.2-10.fc21;x86_64;fedora
E: PackageKit: cannot download Packages/l/libarchive-devel-3.1.2-10.fc21.x86_64.rpm to /var/cache/PackageKit/metadata/fedora/packages/: Cannot download Packages/l/libarchive-devel-3.1.2-10.fc21.x86_64.rpm: All mirrors were tried
I: Complete!
```

Comment: How did you perform the upgrades?

Comment: With dnf system-upgrade.

Comment: You may need to run `dnf distro-sync` after the upgrade to get your system into a consistent state after an upgrade from an older version of Fedora, especially if you are using any third-party repos.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had forgot that step. I did however try it and the problem persists.

Comment: Strange. I hope you're trying to _develop_ this application, as Fedora already includes it! If not, then you're probably wasting a lot of time.

Comment: I was just using gnome-weather because the dependency list is only a single package.